# How to add/update many to many relations with one end of entity in EF core

Tags: c#, many-to-many, asp.net-core-webapi, crud, ef-core-2.2

We have visited quite a few links on EF Core many to many update, yet could not figure a concrete answer to our question and clear our understanding.

Scenario:
We wish to add/update an entity and its related many to many relations in one go like (dbset.Add() or dbset.Update())

We were trying the following and could only add/update the parent entity and not the many-to-many relation list. Can you help us know where we are wrong? and what can be done?

Current Model Structure:

```
        public class Teacher
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Required]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<TeacherDuty> TeacherDuties { get; set; }
    }
    public class Duty
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Required]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<TeacherDuty> TeacherDuties { get; set; }
    }
    public class TeacherDuty
    {
        public long TeacherId { get; set; }
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

        public long DutyId { get; set; }
        public Duty Duty { get; set; }
    }
```

And we are trying to add/update using following methods:

```
public async Task<Teacher> AddTeacher(Teacher pTeacher)
{
    try
    {
        return await _teacher.AddAsync(pTeacher);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
}

public async Task<Teacher> UpdateTeacher(Teacher pTeacher)
{
    try
    {
        return await _teacher.Update(pTeacher);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
}
```

Kindly point us to our misinterpretation of concept and solution if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502829/how-to-update-a-many-to-many-relationship?rq=1

Comment: This doesnt quite give enough info to see why its updating only the parent object. Can you provide a sample of teacher that you are adding with how the task is called

Comment: Following is sample of teacher while update.. ` {
  "Name": "Kasperov",
  "Id": 1,
  "TeacherDuties": [{
    "TeacherId" : 1,
    "DutyId" : 3
  }]
} `  - This is when we want to remove DutyId from 1 and add 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a demo to add and edit a teacher.(`_context` is database context)

**Add a teacher:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Teacher teacher)
    {
        //get your desired dutyId with your own logic
        var SelectedDutyIds = new int[] { 1 };
        var teacherDuties = new List<TeacherDuty>();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(teacher);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


            foreach (var id in SelectedDutyIds)
            {
                var item = new TeacherDuty()
                {
                    TeacherId = teacher.Id,
                    DutyId = id,
                };
                teacherDuties.Add(item);
            }
            _context.AddRange(teacherDuties);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(teacher);
    }
```

**Edit the teacher:** remove all the existing `TeacherDuties` of the teacher firstly and then add new ones.

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long id, Teacher teacher)
    {
        if (id != teacher.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
               //your new dutyIds
                var newSelectedDutyIds = new int[] { 3 };
                var teacherDuties = new List<TeacherDuty>();


                var tdList = await _context.TeacherDuties.Where(td => td.TeacherId == teacher.Id).ToListAsync() ;
                _context.RemoveRange(tdList);

                foreach (var newid in newSelectedDutyIds)
                {
                    var item = new TeacherDuty()
                    {
                        TeacherId = teacher.Id,
                        DutyId = newid,
                    };
                    teacherDuties.Add(item);
                }
                _context.AddRange(teacherDuties);
                _context.Update(teacher);

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!TeacherExists(teacher.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(teacher);
    }
```

Refer to [Entity framework core update many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993860/entity-framework-core-update-many-to-many)