# Asp.net core WebApi endpoint for many to many tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I am developing an asp.net core web API application using an endpoint provided by our designer team. It’s many to many relationships. Below are the tables

**Tables Name:**

1. User (UserId, Name, Gender).
2. Role (RoleId, Title)
3. UserRole (UserId,
   RoleId).

**Relationship:**

- User (1) to (Many) UserRole
- Role(1) to (Many(UserRole).

**Role End Points:**

- GET –> V1/Roles
- POST –> V1/Roles
- PUT –> V1/Roles (Update many recordstogether – JSON Array as request body)
- PUT –> V1/Roles/{RoleId}
- DELETE –> V1/Roles/{RoleId}
- DELETE V1/Roles (DELETE many recordstogether – JSON Array as request body)

**User Endpoints:**

- GET –> V1/Users
- POST –> V1/Users
- PUT –> V1/Users/{UserId}
- DELETE –>V1/Users/{UserId}

**UserRole End points:**

- GET –> V1/ UserRole
- POST –> V1/ UserRole
- PUT –> V1/ UserRole
- DELETE–> V1/ UserRole

**Question:**
Assuming that we have thousands of users and thousands of roles in our organization.
Please advise what is the best practice for designing endpoint for many to many relationships’ tables.

Also, if we want to add, update or delete many users and their assigned roles in one call what is the best way?

I have created the below endpoint for joining tables but not sure. please advice.

- POST –> V1/ UserRole
- PUT –> V1/ UserRole
- DELETE –> V1/ UserRole

In short, How to insert and update many to many. when we have a joining table? I have tried google but not find any example

Comment: Endpoints don't depend on how many thousands of users and thousands of roles you have in db.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. May I know how to design endpoint for many to many tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, if we want to add, update or delete many users and their
> assigned roles in one call what is the best way?
>
> I have created the below endpoint for joining tables but not sure.
> please advice.
>
> POST –> V1/ UserRole
> PUT –> V1/ UserRole
> DELETE –> V1/ UserRole

First, the Endpoints represent units of the app's functionality that are distinct from each other in terms of routing. So it doesn't depend on the count of Users and Roles, but depends on your functionality. You could create the following endpoint:

- POST –> V1/ UserRole   : add user to a role.
- PUT –> V1/ UserRole      : update user's role.
- DELETE –> V1/ UserRole   : delete user from role group.

Since you have already configure the [many to many relationship](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration) between the user and role table, and the UserRole is the join table. When you call the above endpoint, you could query the User and Role table to check whether the user and role (parameter) is existed or not. If not, create a new item. Then update the UserRole table item.

Here are some relate articles about update related entities, you could refer to them:

[Tutorial: Update related data - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Updating many to many relationships in Entity Framework Core](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/updating-many-to-many-relationships-in-entity-framework-core/)

[Entity framework core update many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993860/entity-framework-core-update-many-to-many)

[How to add/update many to many relations with one end of entity in EF core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59695717/how-to-add-update-many-to-many-relations-with-one-end-of-entity-in-ef-core)